# Streaming video with VLC from webcam - errormain access out error: socket bind error (Permission denied)

Tags: sockets, video, video-streaming, vlc

I would like to use the webcam of my old laptop *(my laptop is a Packard Bell EasyNote MX37)* in order to do streaming video.

I try to do this streaming video through VLC by following this [tutorial](http://xmodulo.com/live-stream-video-webcam-linux.html#comment-11378) from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Unfortunately I'm stuck when I apply this command line :

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 :v4l2-standard= :input-slave=alsa://hw:0,0
:live-caching=300
:sout="#transcode{vcodec=WMV2,vb=800,acodec=wma2,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{dst=:8080/stream.wmv}"
```

Indeed, I get this error message:

```
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28)
[0x19....] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[0x7f1................] main access out error: socket bind error (Permission denied)
[0x7f1................] main access out error: socket bind error (Permission denied)
[0x7f1................] main access out error: cannot create socket(s) for HTTP host
[0x7f1................] access_output_http access out error: cannot start HTTP server
[0x7f1................] stream_out_standard stream out error: no suitable sout access module for `http/asf://:8080/stream.wmv'
[0x7f1................] main stream output error: stream chain failed for `transcode{vcodec=WMV2,vb=800,acodec=wma2,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{dst=:8080/stream.wmv}'
[0x7f1................] main input error: cannot start stream output instance, aborting
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

PS: The goal is to keep an eye on my parking space.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error message says, VLC is not allowed to open the port you specified. This might be because it is already in use by another app on your OS or because your user account simply does not have the rights needed to open a port. Consider using a different port like 32000, etc.